# How to get checked row ids in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In the below code I have a jQuery DataTable and I want to get selected row ids and store it into array. But I get only one row id `SchoolID` but I want to get `SchoolID`, `ClassID` and `SectionID` for checked checkbox.

```
var val[]; //global
"aoColumns": [
    {
        "mDataProp": "SchoolID",
        "bSearchable": false,
        "bSortable": false,
        "sWidth": "10%",
        "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
            val = '<input type="checkbox" id="chkSchoolID"  onclick="CheckRow(' + full.SchoolID + ')"></button>';
            return val;
        }
    },
    {
        "mDataProp": "SchoolID",
        "sWidth": "25%"
    }, {
        "mDataProp": "ClassID",
        "sWidth": "25%"
    }, {
        "mDataProp": "SectionID",
        "sWidth": "25%"
    },
],
function CheckRow() {
    alert(val);
}
```

Comment: Is this the full code? Cause the datatable has definitivly a bad syntax (line starting with "aoColumns")

Comment: @SidiaStudios i have placed partial code

Comment: @Dotnet What exactly are you trying to do with `"CheckRow(' + full.SchoolID + ')"`, trying to pass the `full.SchoolID` as an argument? But in your function declaration you don't have any parameters.